# Transforme non-dimension coordinates to classic dimensions

Tags: python-xarray

I have two datasets. One use classic latitude/longitude coordinates. The other xc/yc. The second provided also longitude/latitude but only as non-dimension coordinates.

I need to merge them and do operations based on the latitude/longitude coordinates.

Today, my code looks like this:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ds_1 = xr.Dataset(
    {"foo_1": (("x", "y"), np.random.randn(3, 2)), "foo_2": (("x", "y"), np.random.randn(3, 2))},
    {
        "x": [1, 2, 3],
        "y": [1, 2],
        "longitude": (("y", "x"), [[10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30]]),
        "latitude": (("y", "x"), [[10, 10, 10], [20, 20, 20]]),
    },
)

ds_2 = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "bar_1": (("longitude", "latitude"), np.random.randn(5, 3)),
        "bar_2": (("longitude", "latitude"), np.random.randn(5, 3)),
    },
    {"longitude": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30], "latitude": [10, 15, 20],},
)

ds = xr.merge([ds_1, ds_2])

print("ds_1")
print(ds_1)
print("ds_2")
print(ds_2)
print("ds")
print(ds)

# First plot - works
ds_1["foo_1"].plot(x="longitude", y="latitude")
plt.show()

# Second plot - works
ds["foo_1"].plot(x="x", y="y")
plt.show()

# Third plot - does not work
ds["foo_1"].plot(x="longitude", y="latitude")
plt.show()
```

The output looks like this:

```py
ds_1
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (x: 3, y: 2)
Coordinates:
  * x          (x) int64 1 2 3
  * y          (y) int64 1 2
    longitude  (y, x) int64 10 20 30 10 20 30
    latitude   (y, x) int64 10 10 10 20 20 20
Data variables:
    foo_1      (x, y) float64 -0.5096 0.9541 0.1952 1.475 -0.3975 -0.9002
    foo_2      (x, y) float64 -0.3163 1.533 -0.2353 0.8658 -0.4123 0.6591


ds_2
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 3, longitude: 5)
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) int64 10 15 20 25 30
  * latitude   (latitude) int64 10 15 20
Data variables:
    bar_1      (longitude, latitude) float64 -0.2594 -0.1329 ... 0.1972 0.2836
    bar_2      (longitude, latitude) float64 1.314 -2.089 ... 0.9289 -1.394


ds
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 3, longitude: 5, x: 3, y: 2)
Coordinates:
  * x          (x) int64 1 2 3
  * y          (y) int64 1 2
  * longitude  (longitude) int64 10 15 20 25 30
  * latitude   (latitude) int64 10 15 20
Data variables:
    foo_1      (x, y) float64 -0.5096 0.9541 0.1952 1.475 -0.3975 -0.9002
    foo_2      (x, y) float64 -0.3163 1.533 -0.2353 0.8658 -0.4123 0.6591
    bar_1      (longitude, latitude) float64 -0.2594 -0.1329 ... 0.1972 0.2836
    bar_2      (longitude, latitude) float64 1.314 -2.089 ... 0.9289 -1.394
```

The first plot works like a charm. Not the second one. I got the exception : `x must be one of None, 'x', 'y'` (which is obvious).

The idea is to replace the `xc`/`yc` of the first dataset `ds_1` by `longitude``latitude`. How to operate ?

The longitude and latitude values looks like this in the `ds_1`.

```py
longitude
[[10 20 30]
 [10 20 30]]

latitude
[[10 10 10]
 [20 20 20]]
```

So longitude should become `[10, 20, 30]` and latitude `[10, 20]` ?

### Edit

I created a more generic example

Comment: Does `xr.swap_dims` do what you want?

Comment: It does not seem to work

```ds_1=ds_1.swap_dims({"x":"longitude", "y":"latitude"})```

gives me : 
```ValueError: replacement dimension 'longitude' is not a 1D variable along the old dimension 'x'```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clear example.

Xarray requires `x` and `longitude` to be on the same dimension in order to do things like swap dims. So first of all we need to overwrite the dimension that `longitude` is on:

```
In [18]: ds_ = ds.assign_coords(longitude=(('x',), ds['longitude']))

In [19]: ds_
Out[19]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 3, longitude: 2, x: 2, y: 3)
Coordinates:
  * x          (x) int64 1 2
  * y          (y) int64 1 2 3
  * latitude   (latitude) int64 10 20 30
    longitude  (x) int64 10 20
Data variables:
    foo_1      (x, y) float64 0.9927 -0.1695 -0.4043 -1.55 0.98 -0.2512
    foo_2      (x, y) float64 -0.9058 1.019 0.7127 0.853 -0.1844 1.032
    bar_1      (longitude, latitude) float64 -0.8808 -1.081 ... -0.1703 -1.457
    bar_2      (longitude, latitude) float64 0.4494 1.319 ... 1.299 -0.007001
```

And then we can swap the dims etc:

```
In [21]: ds_.swap_dims(dict(x='longitude'))
Out[21]:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 3, longitude: 2, y: 3)
Coordinates:
    x          (longitude) int64 1 2
  * y          (y) int64 1 2 3
  * latitude   (latitude) int64 10 20 30
  * longitude  (longitude) int64 10 20
Data variables:
    foo_1      (longitude, y) float64 0.9927 -0.1695 -0.4043 -1.55 0.98 -0.2512
    foo_2      (longitude, y) float64 -0.9058 1.019 0.7127 0.853 -0.1844 1.032
    bar_1      (longitude, latitude) float64 -0.8808 -1.081 ... -0.1703 -1.457
    bar_2      (longitude, latitude) float64 0.4494 1.319 ... 1.299 -0.007001
```

Comment: But it works only because the two datasets are using the same longitude/latitude, isn't it?

In the case, they are not aligned on the same grid (one of the datasets has more resolution for example), this code does not work (I should have shown a more generic example).
I got this error: `conflicting sizes for dimension 'x': length 3 on 'longitude' and length 2 on 'foo_1'`.

In our code, we perform the resampling later depending the user needs.

Comment: How do you expect the data to move between dimensions with different length indexes? Maybe edit the example

Comment: I created a more generic example. I hope it's clear :)

Btw : thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. I think what might help is defining what you want the dataset to look like separately from the plot. IIUC, `x` and `y` are `2` x `3` respectively, but `longitude` and `latitude` are `6` & `6` — so I'm not sure exactly how to make that transformation. I thought it might be `ds_1.stack(z=['x','y'])` but not sure if that's right either.

Comment: Finally, I had time to find a solution. Not the most elegant one.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to define replace the latitude and longitude with 1D array.

This probably not the most direct way.

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


ds_1 = xr.Dataset(
    {"foo_1": (("x", "y"), np.random.randn(3, 2)), "foo_2": (("x", "y"), np.random.randn(3, 2))},
    {
        "x": [1, 2, 3],
        "y": [1, 2],
        "longitude": (("y", "x"), [[10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30]]),
        "latitude": (("y", "x"), [[10, 10, 10], [20, 20, 20]]),
    },
)

## Transform the dataset coords
def getDimension(ds, dim:str):
    """
    Find which array is corresponding to the dimension
    """

    dim_1 = ds[dim].values[:,0]
    dim_2 = ds[dim].values[0,:]

    if not list(dim_1).count(dim_1[0]) == len(dim_1):
        return dim_1
    elif not list(dim_2).count(dim_2[0]) == len(dim_2):
        return dim_2
    else:
        return None

latitude = getDimension(ds_1, 'latitude')
longitude = getDimension(ds_1, 'longitude')

ds_1 = ds_1.assign_coords({'longitude':(('x',), longitude), 'latitude':(('y',), latitude)})
ds_1 = ds_1.swap_dims({"x":"longitude", "y":"latitude"})


ds_2 = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "bar_1": (("longitude", "latitude"), np.random.randn(5, 3)),
        "bar_2": (("longitude", "latitude"), np.random.randn(5, 3)),
    },
    {"longitude": [10, 15, 20, 25, 30], "latitude": [10, 15, 20],},
)

ds = xr.merge([ds_1, ds_2])

print("ds_1")
print(ds_1)
print("ds_2")
print(ds_2)
print("ds")
print(ds)

# First plot - works
ds_1["foo_1"].plot(x="longitude", y="latitude")
plt.show()

# Second plot - does not work
# ds["foo_1"].plot(x="x", y="y")
# plt.show()

# Third plot - work
ds["foo_1"].plot(x="longitude", y="latitude")
plt.show()
```